# How to choose iterator by condition in Python

Tags: python, iterator

I have 2 dictionaries, I want to use .iteritems() on one of them.

I would like to have something that preforms like this:

```
if (condition):
    for index, item in dict1.iteritems():
         //have some code here
else:
    for index, item in dict2.iteritems():
        //have SAME code here
```

I wish not to copy the code in the loop twice, and wish to find an option without making a function for it. Is there any convenient way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: `my_dict = dict1 if condition else dict2`?

Comment: Not related, but as far as I know `iteritems()` is a Python2 method. Please consider moving to Python3

Comment: Thanks, I dont know why I was afraid to use it with dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case, I'd rather choose the dict before iterating:

```
d = dict1 if condition else dict2
for index, item in d.items():  # iteritems is no longer needed in Python 3
    ...
```